# Deleting a row from dynamic table when click on image

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am working on a PHP/MySQL grid that list two little icons, one is expected to delete the actual register and remove the row and the other is supposed to redirect the user to another page opening the details of the selected register.
This is how my code looks like:

PHP:

```
$output .='<tr id="'.$id.'">';
$output .='<td align="center">'.$expiration_date.'</td>';
$output .='<td>'.$title.'</td>';
$output .='<td>'.$title_pt.'</td>';
$output .='<td align="center">'.$last_update.'</td>';
$output .='<td align="center">'.$active_pack.'</td>';
$output .='<td align="center" class="icon_grid"><a id="edit" title="Open the register." href="special_pack_open.php?id='.$id.'"><img src="images/Write2.gif" width="16" height="16" /></a></td>';
$output .='<td align="center" class="icon_grid"><a id="delete" title="Delete the register." href="#"><img src="images/Trash.gif" width="16" height="16" /></a></td>';
$output .='</tr>';
```

JQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('table tr[id]').click(function(){
        $(this).closest("tr").remove();
        var obj = $(this);
         $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: 'delete_package.php',
           data: { pk_id: obj.attr("id")},
           dataType: "json",
           success: function(data, evt) {
           if (data.success == "true") {
               alert('The record has been deleted successfuly!');
           } else {
               alert('error');
           }
           }
        })
    })
})
</script>
```

Everything is working very good. When I click in the Trash.gif, it deletes the register and remove the row. The thing is when I click on the Write2.Gif (second link) where it is supposed to go to the next page, it does the same action as delete does!
How can I change my JQuery code to make it understand that only one link is dedicated to delete the register?

Thank you.

Comment: You bound your click event to the whole row `$('table tr[id]')` -> if you click anywhere on the row (be it your trash or your write icon), your ajax request (delete) is fired.. Bind the click events to your `a` tags, eg `$("#edit").click(..)`

Answer (score 0):

`$("table tr[id]")` is the selector for any `tr` that is a descendant of `table` that has any `id` attribute at all.  You need a more specific selector.

As you will have many rows, you should probably be using a *class* instead of an *id* for edit/delete.

```
$(".delete").on("click", function () { /* your code */
```

You may also need to delegate the event

```
$("#id-of-table").on("click", ".delete"
```

Comment: I've changed my code giving a class for each link like for delete class="delete" and I changed the jquery just like this: $("#tabela tr[id]").on("click", ".delete", function () { it works now but isn't posting the id to the PHP script that is in charge of deleting the register from MySQL database.

Comment: @AlexAraujo use `var obj = $(this).closest("tr[id]")`

Comment: **Awesome.** It is working very good @ExplosionPills. I delegated the event and it is posting with 'var obj = $(this).closest("tr[id]")'. Great help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that experienced with jQuery, but it appears that your selector is causing the deletion function to be associated with the click event of the tr.  Try it with $('#delete').click instead of $('table tr[id]').click.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('table tr[id]').click(function(){
        $(this).closest("tr").remove();
        var obj = $(this);
         $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: 'delete_package.php',
           data: { pk_id: obj.attr("id")},
           dataType: "json",
           success: function(data, evt) {
           if (data.success == "true") {
               alert('The record has been deleted successfuly!');
           } else {
               alert('error');
           }
           }
        })
    })
})
</script>
```

replace this $('table tr[id]') with this $('a#delete')

Comment: But if I do this how the id of the TR will be posted to the PHP script that is in charge of delete the register from MySQL database?

Comment: $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');